# I need to prove that $\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|\log(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-verification

I need to prove the following limit

$$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|\log(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$

Using the Squeeze Theorem

$$0\le|\frac{|x|\log(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}|\leq\frac{|x|\log(1+y)}{y}\to0$$
For $(x,y)\to(0,0)$

Here I have used the fact that 
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\ge\sqrt{y^2}=y$$
Such that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\frac{1}{y}$$

And the fact that

$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\log(1+y)}{y} =0$$

So I can conclude that

$$0\le\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|\log(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\le\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|\log(1+y)}{y}\le0$$

And thus by the Squeeze Theorem 
$$\lim_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|\log(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0$$

Is my proof correct?

Comment: Almost correct. Except  $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\log(1+y)}{y} = 1 \neq 0$.

Comment: I think you need one more step. $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \dfrac{|x|\log(1+y)}{|y|} = \left(\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}|x|\right)\left(\displaystyle \lim_{y \to 0}\dfrac{\log(1+y)}{|y|}\right) = 0\cdot 1 = 0$$ But, otherwise, this looks correct.

Comment: Now that I see my mistake I see that $\lim_{y\to0} \frac{\log(1+y)}{|y|}$ does not exist because for $y\to0^+$ we have that the limit is 1, instead for $y\to0^-$ the limit is -1. I think this approach is not correct.

Comment: The main point is not so much that the limit is $+1$ or $-1$, it's that it's not $0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost correct. Except  $\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\log(1+y)}{y} = 1 \neq 0$.

Here's how  I would  do  it:

Because $(|x|-|y|)^2\geq 0$, we have $x^2+y^2\geq 2|xy|$ (this  is also known as [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means)).

Therefore, $$\frac 1 {\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq \frac 1 {\sqrt{2|xy|}}$$
and $$\left|\frac{x\log(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|\leq \frac{\sqrt{|x|}}{\sqrt 2} \cdot\frac{|\log(1+y)|}{\sqrt{|y|}}$$

Now $$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{|\log(1+y)|}{\sqrt{|y|}}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{|\log(1+y)|}{|y|}\sqrt{|y|}=1\cdot 0 = 0$$
So by the squeeze theorem, you  get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Carefull: $\sqrt{y^2}=|y|$ and

$$\lim_{y\to0}\frac{\log(1+y)}{y} =\lim_{y\to0}\log(1+y)^{1\over y}= \log e =1$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{aligned}
& \lim_{(x, y)\to(0,0)}\frac{|x|\log(1+y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} \xrightarrow{\begin{cases}x=r \cdot \cos\theta
\\ y=r \cdot \sin\theta
\end{cases}}\lim_{r\to 0}{\frac{|r \cdot \cos\theta| \ln{(1+r \cdot \sin\theta)} }{ \sqrt{(r \cdot \cos\theta)^2+(r \cdot \sin\theta)^2} } }
\\& \le \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{|r \cdot \cos\theta|(r\cdot \sin\theta)}{ \sqrt{(r \cdot \cos\theta)^2+(r \cdot \sin\theta)^2} }= \lim_{r\to 0}\frac{r ^2\cdot| \cos\theta|(\sin\theta)}{r}=\lim_{r\to 0} r\cdot| \cos\theta|(\sin\theta)
\\& \le \lim_{r\to 0} r\cdot1 =0
\end{aligned}$